# Limit for $n\to\infty$ with the sine

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

It is true that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(n\pi\sin{n\pi}\right)=0\,$? I thought that $\sin{n\pi}=0$ and so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (n\pi\cdot0)=0\;.$

Comment: If $n \in \mathbb N$, yes. If $n \in \mathbb R$, the limit does not exist.

Comment: @player3236 There is an unwritten rule that states that $n$ in math is a natural number(Just joking obviously).

Comment: Your question is slightly...weird. You ask if something's true, then you say you thought that...it is true ! So what did you **really** mean to ask?

Comment: I'm just wondering if my idea is right ... if I had been sure of my intuition I wouldn't have asked for anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since $\;\sin(n\pi)=0\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;$ every term of the sequence is $\;0\;$ and so the limit is $\;0\;.$